# Insert one node at the head of the circular doubly linked lists using java

Tags: java, circular-list

I want to create a method that inserts one node at the head of the circular doubly linked lists using java. How I can I do this?

I know the first node to replace it with the new one, the same for the last one. I did not get how can I know the 'last' while the list is circular?

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far, and maybe what you have tried?

Comment: The last node is the node where `next == first`